Get accessToken from certificate
I am trying to connect external system,  but they have given .PEM certificate file. I checked with for clientId and ClientSecrect, but they didn't provided that. I checked salesforce documentation to get access token from certificate and I found option to do using named credential.  But didn't get an option to upload. PEM file.
External system is PowerBi.
In POC they provided client, secrect and using HTTP class I got access token. But now they denied to provide clientid,secrect.
Provided .PEM file.

A certificate is not an access token (given the usual meaning of "certificate"), so you can't take the certificate and get an access token out of it alone. The premise of your question is currently flawed. You're going to need to add a lot more detail here. What is this external system (Salesforce? something else?) are they using OAuth 2.0? If so, are they using the JWT flow (which is the one that would use a certificate)? [Edit] your question to add those details.

Derek is right. Forget about Access Token. Read this

@FelixvanHove I suppose that depends on the direction of the connection. OP should still add more details to their question (including but not only "is Power BI connecting to Salesforce, or is Salesforce connecting to Power BI?")

It appeared to me quite clear from the first sentence that OP tries to connect to the external system (Power Bi) and was given a .PEM file. The POC implied getting an access token by means of the usual client whatnot that "they provided". I don't see how that still "depends on the direction of the connection", but maybe I missed something?!

Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. PEM is an encoding for all kinds of crypto material, the term "certificate" is vague, Talk to your client to better understand their needs, then update your question.

@FelixvanHove Because the "Upload a User Authentication Certificate" feature, at first blush, appears to just be about authenticating into Salesforce. It doesn't sound like it would apply if you're trying to make a callout to an external system.

@DerekF, gosh, in this respect you are right: the link above might be misleading. Thanks for pointing out!
